# Relations between Laplacian and Fourier transform

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, fourier-analysis

I have been thinking this question for a couple of days. To be more specific, I want to derive an explicit expression of Fourier transform under some coordinate chart of a manifold. What I do have right now is the Riemannian metric and associated Laplace-Beltrami operator under this chart. Does anyone have some suggestions on what I can do to obtain the expression of the Fourier transform starting from the Laplacian? For example, if the coordinate chart is $(x,y,z)$ and Laplace-Beltrami operator is given by
$$
\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}-2c\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(f(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)
$$
where $c$ is some constant and $f(z)$ is a smooth function of $z$, what will be the expression for the Fourier transform? Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you know the spectral decomposition of the $\Delta$ operator, its eigenfunctions ? is it self-adjoint ?